# VB.NET - Ctrl + Break suspends code on "Partial Class frmMain"

Tags: vb.net, ide, windows-forms-designer

This is an IDE question for Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition. It might be a bug in the IDE, or maybe it's my fault somehow?

My main form is named `frmMain` and in my application's properties I have set `frmMain` as my startup object. All of that seems like what a lot of software engineers do.

But while debugging I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, as I have done for years, and I get an behavior in the IDE that I wasn't expecting. Upon doing so, I get the green background text and the green arrow indicating in a tooltip:

> This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function.

Even if I didn't have the designer document open, it automatically opens `frmMain.Designer.vb` in the editor and hihglights line in green. The line is of course: `Partial Class frmMain` which is line 2 of the file. (Yes, it's highlighting the second line of the designer-generated code.)

`frmMain` seems to have fully loaded and it's my startup object. As far as I know, there shouldn't be a "next statement to execute" at all because code should be idle. I don't want to see the `Designer.vb` document... I want to edit my own code.

What's causing this? Even though my form is behaving just fine, could there somehow be an unfinished aspect of loading the form such that it is "not returning" from a function?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Okay, now it gets interesting.  I thought I found a solution here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  But I was wrong because MY IDE doesn't present a "debugger node" so that I can turn "Just My Code" on as Microsoft advises.  Microsoft says it's there, and it just plain isn't.  The nodes I show are Environment, Projects and Solutions, Text Editor, Database Tools, and Windows Forms Designer... There is NO "Debugger node" so I can't follow their instructions.  Something is definitely screwey here.

Comment: Don't make us guess at this.  Post a snippet with a couple of lines of code around the green line.  And post the stack trace.

Comment: You have a checkbox in the lower left hand corner of your Options form called "show all settings". Make sure it is checked, you should see your debugger node then.

Comment: To Hans and Mark: Please note I've added screen shots to my original question.  The stack trace is shown, and the "show all settings" is indeed checked.  I have read that the Debugger node isn't available in VB Express 2008, but it still doesn't clarify how the "Just My Code" option seems to have become disabled, and how I can re-enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own:

### I checked the "Enable application framework" checkbox in the solution's properties, and all is well!

I believe this issue arose when I was working on experimental code in which I had desired to make Sub Main my startup object.  I had cleared the checkbox because doing so is necessary to use Sub Main.

When the experiment didn't pan out I reset the startup object back to frmMain, and my app worked fine.  However I had not re-checked the box.  I hadn't noticed the change in the IDE behavior for several days (when I needed the more standard behavior) so I had not observed any correlation.

Although checking that box is definitely the solution, it's still not exactly clear to me is what the heck this box actually does, other than cause me to spend a lot of time on StackOverflow.com!  ;-)

To others who encounter a similar situation, I'm now quite confident that my settings were not corrupt, and if you're using the Express edition, please don't be mislead by MS documentation which may lead you to believe it's the "Just My Code" option.  This option cannot be changed in the Express versions.  (But it's not because you can't turn it on -- It's because you can't turn it OFF in Express!)

Thanks to everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it is trying to show you the equivalent of:

```
Application.Run(new frmMain)
```

This is the code that gets generated to startup your form. But in VB.NET this code gets burried. Create a `Main()` function and change your startup type to that with this line in it and repeat the process. You'll see it highlight `Application.Run`. That is the method that contains your Windows message pump loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Basic compiler will add an entry point in your form. The entry point is the standard main function or "shared sub main", which in turn contains the code "application.run(new form)". Since this is compiler generated code there is no source location, so the Visual Basic editor highlights the class definition.

The clue to this is in the call stack. Notice the `Main()`.

```
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.Run(new frmMain)
End Sub
```

Comment: To AMissico and to tcarvin: Really, I get it. But this isn't normal behavior for VB.Net. After some research it seems the option "Just My Code" has become disabled in my particular IDE installation.  It is enabled by default in VB.Net. (Which I like.  I find it very convenient as I can edit code in break mode, try different snippets without restarting and without the code jumping to an irrelevant line.) UNFORTUNATELY, the Express edition's UI doesn't provide a way to re-enable it. So my 2 questions are: How did "Just My Code" get turned off? And how to re-enable it in the 2008 Express edition?

Comment: "Just My Code" is enabled by default regardless of language.

Comment: It is possible your Visual Studio settings are corrupt. Try to reset. There is a command-line to do this if not available through the UI.

Comment: This is normal behavior for VB.NET and Windows Forms applications when you set the startup form. WPF does a similiar thing for both VB.NET and C#. As tcarvin mentions, Windows Forms needs a "windows-message-pump" which is created through the `Application.Run` and all applications must have a main entry point.

Comment: >>But I was wrong because MY IDE doesn't present a "debugger node" so that I can turn "Just My Code" on as Microsoft advises. Microsoft says it's there, and it just plain isn't.<< Then your settings are definitely corrupted.

Comment: I have reset my settings, and I get the same results.  To be clear: I have read in several places that the debugger node is not available in the Express editions.  (Although Just My Code is still on by default.)  At this point I'm tend to be less convinced that Just My Code option is actually my problem.